# Creating a navigation menu to see where you are on your website

Tags: menus, navigation

I want to create a "navigation" menu - I don't know what they are called and I'm having a hard time googling it as it is not a navigation menu as such or a sub-menu or pull down menu ect. 
I just want something showing you where you are on the website, what pages where before and such(like the picture shown below) I am using elementor, would that be a problem?
I really hope you can help me! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Look for `Breadcrumbs`.  There are many plugins and snippets out there for this like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb/ and I think Yoast SEO even has this capability: https://yoast.com/help/implement-wordpress-seo-breadcrumbs/

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was about to go insane.

Comment: Anytime... Hppy to help!